# How to implement an iOS BGProcessingTask in Flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, background-task

I am implementing an app which uses ML to analyse user's gallery and I need to schedule this task to fire **in background**.
This task is too big for iOS [BGAppRefreshTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgapprefreshtask), I found that I need to use [BGProcessingTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtask) for this purpose.
The question is: **how can I implement calling a function in background?**
I saw packages such as [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) or [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager), but as far as I'm concerned they are for BGAppRefreshTask max.

Comment: [this package](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager), despite mentioning `BGAppRefreshTask` in its Readme, actually submits `BGProcessingTasks`

Comment: Also see https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/295